# Solutions to $u \circ v - v \circ u = \mathrm{Id}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(E,\Vert \cdot \Vert)$ be an infinite-dimensional normed vector space and $\mathcal{L}_{c}(E)$ denote the ring of continuous endomorphisms of $E$. I would like to determine whether the equation

$$ u \circ v - v \circ u = \mathrm{Id}_{E} \quad ; \quad (u,v) \in \Big( \mathcal{L}_{c}(E) \Big)^{2} \tag{$\star$} $$

has solutions. I was asked to prove first that, if $n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$ and $(u,v) \in \Big( \mathcal{L}_{c}(E) \Big)^{2}$ such that $u \circ v - v \circ u = \mathrm{Id}_{E}$, then : $u^{n} \circ v - v \circ u^{n} = n u^{n-1}$. This can be proved easily by induction on $n$. Then, I would like to use this result to determine whether $(\star)$ has solutions. Here is what I tried :

Let us assume that $(\star)$ has a solution $(u,v)$ in $\Big( \mathcal{L}_{c}(E) \Big)^{2}$. Consider the mapping :

$$ \Phi_{v} \, : \, \mathcal{L}_{c}(E) \, \longrightarrow \, \mathcal{L}_{c}(E) $$

such that : $\forall w \in \mathcal{L}_{c}(E), \, \Phi_{v}(w) = w \circ v - v \circ w$. Then, $\Phi_{v} \in \mathcal{L}_{c}\Big( \mathcal{L}_{c}(E) \Big)$ because $\Phi_{v}$ is linear and :

$$ \forall w \in \mathcal{L}_{c}(E), \, \Vert w \Vert \leq 1, \, \Vert \Phi_{v}(w) \Vert \leq 2 \Vert v \Vert. $$

It follows that :

$$ n \Vert u^{n-1} \Vert = \Vert \Phi_{v}(u^n) \Vert \leq 2 \Vert v \Vert \Vert u^{n} \Vert \leq 2 \Vert v \Vert \Vert u \Vert \Vert u^{n-1} \Vert.$$

Which leads to : $n \leq 2 \Vert u \Vert \Vert v \Vert$. This inequality cannot hold for all $n$ in $\mathbb{N}^{\ast}$. The equation $u \circ v - v \circ u = \mathrm{Id}_{E}$ therefore has no solution in $\Big( \mathcal{L}_{c}(E) \Big)^2$.

Is that right? Or did I miss something?

Comment: This equation is very important in physics and it is well known that are no continuous solutions. There is a number of different ways to prove that there are none.

Comment: @MarkJoshi : Thank you ! I did not know this equation was used in Physics (in which field?). If my proof is not correct, at least the conclusion is.

Comment: quantum physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is *correct*.  However, there are a few things you write that are strange notationally.  Two aesthetic corrections:

- Say $u,v \in \mathcal L_c(E)$ rather than $(u,v) \in \mathcal L_c(E)^2$
- Make your logical statements clearer: $\forall w \in \mathcal{L}_{c}(E): \, \Vert w \Vert \leq 1 \implies \Vert \Phi_{v}(w) \Vert \leq 2 \Vert v \Vert$

---

A note for those wondering about the induction: note that
$$
[u^n,v] = u[u^{n-1},v] + [u^{n-1},v]u - u[u^{n-2},v]u
$$
where $[a,b]$ denotes $ab - ba$.